# Why do parasitic elements (e.g capacitance) appear on only high frequencies?

Tags: capacitor, impedance, transmission-line, high-speed, parasitic-capacitance

We know that the impedance of a capacitor is inversely proportional to the frequency then why is it not negligible when at higher frequencies ?

Comment: They don't. They're always there. They just matter more.

Comment: With higher frequencies capacitors become lower impedances. Parasitic elements will show these low impedances _at places where you don't want them_. That's why they're called _parasitic_. It's the same with relatively low 10 - 100 MOhm surface resistance on a PCB - in the thousands of volts or nano ampere range they matter hugely. That said, could you please clarify why parasitic properties could be "negligible"?

Answer (score 3):

Shunt stray capacitances are problematic when their impedance is too low, as opposite to being too high, because they pull down signal lines and/or mismatches them.

When the stray capacitance value and frequency are both low, then the resulting impedance is high enough so as not to heavily impair a line. Everything might be reasonably under control.

However, as frequency goes up this ceases to be true, and then the resulting impedance becomes low enough so as to pull down the line.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I'm not sure your edit makes sense. What does it mean for the stray capacitance value to be lower than the frequency? You can't compare farads and hertz. I get what you're saying, but I don't think that's a good way to word it.

Comment: I don't know, but thats what three OP said originally, there was an edit that looked confusing so it would be best if the OP could clarify

Answer (score 2):

the assumption *Why do parasitic elements (e.g capacitance) appear on only high frequencies?* in question is false.  It appears at any frequency but impedance lowers with rising frequency.

Parasitic capacitance is always frequency dependant impedance. Zc=1/2piCf

Thus 1pF at 60Hz is pretty high but compared to 10M resistor can be used to detect 50/60 Hz stray signals for a hand wave proximity power light switch to couple stray Efield into a comparator and toggle or click an up/down counter to dim up down with simple logic to control phase on a triac.

been there, done that 1970.

### added

2nd question... *why is it not negligible at high frequency*
If we use caps for coupling then we assume short circuit impedance.

But you don't want stray insulation to attenuate, cause crosstalk or reflections on signals, so stray pF is important.

Answer (score 2):

If the capacitor is considered to be JUST a capacitor, then its impedance does approach zero as frequency increases. BUT

The key is in your question title - specifically, "parasitic". You cannot consider a capacitor to be simply a capacitor. Simply by having physical length it also possesses inductance. So a simple model looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKK7tS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For non-RF components and low frequencies, L is negligeable. As frequency rises the drop in the impedance in C greatly outweighs any contribution from L, but the impedance of L does rise.

At some frequency, called self-resonance, the impedance of L equals the impedance of C, and this forms a minimum overall impedance. For greater frequencies the increase in impedance of L is greater than the decrease in impedance in C, so the total impedance rises with frequency.

And all of this, of course, ignores resistive effects.

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at it:

A very low impedance is a short circuit. Short circuits can have a dramatic impact on circuit performance.

Another way to look at it:

Many times, a parasitic capacitor is placed so that you should be worried about its admittance, not its impedance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a resistor: for DC, it has 10MΩ || parallel parasitic capacity 1pF.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f73H4b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, for DC, that 1pF doesn't matter. But what happens at 100 MHz? That 1 pF now has a conductivity of \$j\omega C1 = j \cdot 2\pi 10^8\,\text{Hz} \cdot 10^{-12}\, \text F \approx 6 \cdot 10^{-4}\,\text S\$. The ideal R1 is still 10 MΩ, i.e. has an inverse \$10^{-7} \,\text S\$: in other words, the resistance suddenly is reduced by a huge factor!

Comment: You should switch the labels "R1_real" vs. "R1_ideal"

Comment: @try-catch-finally no. The right part of the schematic illustrates the left, "real" part being a composition of an ideal resistor and an ideal capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to consider the parasitic inductances: pcb traces(1nH/mm), pcb vias (~1nH, depending of height/width ratio), pcb planes (10% of what a trace would be), bond wires in the ICs (0.5nH each), leadframes (go with 1nH/mm), and the silicon inductances. Assume every pin of every IC has to work in a 10nanoHenry environment, until proven to be smaller.

For fun and games, consider the parasitic onchip VDD---GND capacitance, often 100pF or 1,000pF or larger. That resonates with the pin inductance. Perhaps the bulk silicon resistances and well_contacts and substrate_contacts and metal resistance will adequately dampen: Rd = sqrt(L/C) is good trial value.

Note 100pF and 10nH resonate at 50MHz. Lots of small MCUs, with one set of VDD/GDD, will ring at that frequency.

Is 50MHz high frequency?

The parasitic inductance of a bypass capacitor --- labeled ESL --- prevents ideal filtering action. 500uF and 20nH (20milliMeter size cap)  resonate at 50.3KHz. Not a high frequency, eh?